# Intellij recompile all classes before Jar build

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build

I'm working on a project that builds a JAR file but for some reason I have to manually recompile all the classes prior to build. I had read that in the run/debug configuration settings there is a "before launch" option to add pre-build tasks, however I don't see an option to rebuild the classes.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

[image]

Comment: Why do you have to manually compile your classes? Obviously, your classes need to be recompiled if changes have been made since the last compilation, but IntelliJ can compile them for you quite easily.

Comment: It's not currently doing that with my above configuration, and the tutorials that are around do not seem to pertain to what I have going on.

Comment: Mentioned Run configuration  runs external JAR file. So it doesn't suggest to build project as project not relate to the JAR. You could add "Build Artifact" action to make IDE recompile your classes and build artifact.